# HTML CSS - Organizar imagens(figure) com legendas(figcaption) na página?

Tags: html, html5, style, css

Estou com dificuldade de colocar a legenda dentro da minha imagem, quero que a legenda fique na parte inferior da imagem(Dentro dela), outra coisa é que minha section.galeria não está dentro da minha div#interface e também não consigo centralizar a mesma.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.postagem {
 background-color: rgba(255,140,40,.05);
 margin: 0px;
}
#interface {
 width: 1200px;
 background-color: white;
 margin: 90px auto 10px auto;
 box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.cabecalho {
 transition: 0.2s;
 top: 0px;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 35px;
 background-color: rgba(255,140,40,1);
 margin: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 padding-top: 20px;
 text-align: center;
} 
.logo {
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 font-family: agency fb;
 font-size: 20pt;
 /*display: inline-block;*/
}
#fcor {
 color: rgba(255,220,180,1);
}
.galeria {
 margin-left: auto;
 padding: 20px;
 width: 1200px;
 }
.legenda {
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
}
.imgp{
 position: relative;
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 0px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: white;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
 float: left;
}
/*Postagens*/

#postagem02 {
 background-color: white;
 background: url("../_imagens/win10.jpg") no-repeat;
 background-size: 200px 200px;
}
#postagem03 {
 background-color: white;
 background: url("../_imagens/oracle.png") no-repeat;
 background-size: 200px 200px;
}
#postagem05 {
 background-color: white;
 background: url("../_imagens/vnc.png") no-repeat;
 background-size: 200px 200px;
}
#postagem04 {
 background-color: white;
 background: url("../_imagens/office.jpg") no-repeat;
 background-size: 200px 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Processos e Manuais de Instruções</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/estilo.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/fotos.css"/>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).scroll(function() {
 var y = $(this).scrollTop();
 if (y < 25) {
  $('.cabecalho').css({'padding-top': '20px','padding-bottom': '20px'});
 } else {
  $('.cabecalho').css({'padding-top': '5px', 'padding-bottom': '0px'});
 }
 });
 </script>
</head>
<body class="postagem">
  <header class="cabecalho">
   <h1 class="logo">MANUAIS E PROCESSOS<span id="fcor"> INFORMÁTICA<span><h1/>
  </header>
 <div id="interface">
  <section class="galeria">
   <a href="_postagem/1009182.html"><figure><img class="imgp" src="https://image.ibb.co/cXVJ79/check.jpg"><figcaption class="legenda">Legenda Checklist</figcaption></figure></a>
   <a href="_postagem/1009182.html"><figure><img class="imgp" src="https://image.ibb.co/gabEfU/win10.jpg"><figcaption class="legenda">Legenda Windows 10</figcaption><a href="_postagem/1009181.html"></a></figure>
   <a href="_postagem/1009182.html"><figure><img class="imgp" src="https://image.ibb.co/eiiGup/oracle.png"><figcaption class="legenda">Legenda Oracle</figcaption><a href="_postagem/1009182.html"></a></figure>
   <a href="_postagem/1009182.html"><figure><img class="imgp" src="https://image.ibb.co/deNLLU/office.png"><figcaption class="legenda">Legenda Office</figcaption><a href="_postagem/1009182.html"></a></figure>
   <a href="_postagem/1009182.html"><figure><img class="imgp" src="https://image.ibb.co/cRLwup/vnc.png"><figcaption class="legenda">Legenda VNC</figcaption><a href="_postagem/1009182.html"></a></figure>
   
  </section>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara sua estrutura de HTML tinha alguns problemas, tipo um uma tag `<a>` dentro de outra tag `<a>`. Isso não é correto. Outro problema é que vc usa float:left em alguns elementos, por isso estava dando a impressão que a `section.galeria` não estava dentro da `div#interface`. Além disso, alguns `position` estavam no lugar errado...

Fiz alguns ajustes e agora acho que ficou como vc queria. Da uma olhada, exiba como "Página toda" para ver melhor o resultado:

```js
$(document).scroll(function () {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y < 25) {
    $('.cabecalho').css({
      'padding-top': '20px',
      'padding-bottom': '20px'
    });
  } else {
    $('.cabecalho').css({
      'padding-top': '5px',
      'padding-bottom': '0px'
    });
  }
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

.postagem {
  background-color: rgba(255, 140, 40, .05);
  margin: 0px;
}

#interface {
  width: 1200px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 90px auto 10px auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

#interface::after,
.galeria::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.cabecalho {
  transition: 0.2s;
  top: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 140, 40, 1);
  margin: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  font-family: agency fb;
  font-size: 20pt;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
}

#fcor {
  color: rgba(255, 220, 180, 1);
}

.galeria {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.galeria a figure{
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  text-align: center;
}
.galeria a figure img{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.legenda {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 10px;
  margin: auto;
}


/*Postagens*/

#postagem02 {
  background-color: white;
  background: url("../_imagens/win10.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: 200px 200px;
}

#postagem03 {
  background-color: white;
  background: url("../_imagens/oracle.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 200px 200px;
}

#postagem05 {
  background-color: white;
  background: url("../_imagens/vnc.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 200px 200px;
}

#postagem04 {
  background-color: white;
  background: url("../_imagens/office.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: 200px 200px;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body class="postagem">
 <header class="cabecalho">
  <h1 class="logo">MANUAIS E PROCESSOS<span id="fcor"> INFORMÁTICA</span>
     </h1>
 </header>
  
 <div id="interface">
  <section class="galeria">
   <a href="_postagem/1009182.html">
    <figure>
     <img class="imgp" src="https://image.ibb.co/cXVJ79/check.jpg">
     <figcaption class="legenda">Legenda Checklist</figcaption>
    </figure>
   </a>
   <a href="_postagem/1009182.html">
    <figure>
     <img class="imgp" src="https://image.ibb.co/gabEfU/win10.jpg">
     <figcaption class="legenda">Legenda Windows 10</figcaption>
    </figure>
   </a>
   <a href="_postagem/1009182.html">
    <figure><img class="imgp" src="https://image.ibb.co/eiiGup/oracle.png">
     <figcaption class="legenda">Legenda Oracle</figcaption>
    </figure>
   </a>
   <a href="_postagem/1009182.html">
    <figure>
     <img class="imgp" src="https://image.ibb.co/deNLLU/office.png">
     <figcaption class="legenda">Legenda Office</figcaption>
    </figure>
   </a>
   <a href="_postagem/1009182.html">
    <figure>
     <img class="imgp" src="https://image.ibb.co/cRLwup/vnc.png">
     <figcaption class="legenda">Legenda VNC</figcaption>
    </figure>
   </a>

  </section>
 </div>
```